# Wrong answer in dice game

Tags: python

I have to calculate if you win or lose money in the long run . You throw 4 dices and if the eyes are less than 9, you win 10 euros. for every game the buy in price is 1 euro. So the answer should be negative when r is 10. What is wrong with my code?

```
import sys
from numpy import *
r = int(sys.argv[1])  # Profit in the game
N = int(sys.argv[2])  # number of experiments
d = 4                 # number of dices thrown at once
M = 0                 # startcapital
for i in xrange(N):
    M -= 1            # buy in
    eyes = 0
    for j in range(d):
        eyes = random.randint(1,7, d)
    success = eyes < 9
    M = sum(success)

profit_in_long_run = (M) / float(N)
print 'profit in game', profit_in_long_run
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your code, but the biggest one is that you are not accumulating the `eyes` but only getting the last one which will always be <= 6.

You want:

```
eyes = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    euro -= q
    for i in range(n):
        eyes += random.randint(1,6)
```

or possibly this:

```
for i in xrange(N):
    euro -= q
    eyes = 0
    for i in range(n):
        eyes += random.randint(1,6)
    if eyes < 9:
        euro += r
```

(I'm not entirely familiar with how this game is played).

In either case, you want to accumulate the number of "eyes" (or "pips") over either n or n*N rolls.

Using distinct variables with the names `n` and `N` seems deliberately confusing, by the way.

Comment: You are supposed to thwrow the 4 dices at once, so when the sum of the eyes are less than 9, you win 10 euros

Comment: Then you want the second version.  It will deduct `q` once for each game, then take the total of four throws and, if the total is less than 9 give a reward of `r`. (Note that I just fixed a cut-and-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

`eyes` is defined to be a random number between `1` and `6`, so your test `if eyes < 9` will always be true.

Also, by using meaningless variable names like `q`, `p` and `r`, you're making it hard to understand what you're trying to do. A month from now, you probably won't remember either :)

For example, you have three variables that (according to your code) all mean "profit" - `p`, `r` and `profit`. That doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

If I use the program and change the r the answer definitely changes.

Your error is probably with eyes, you roll a dice N * n times but only check the last one. On top of that you roll between 1 and 6 and then ask if the number is below 9, which it will always be.

As commented above I would suggest changed your variable names. Also you use for both loops i as variable, that is usually bad practice.

Rewriting this you can also just say: p = -q + r - q / N